# How do I make a self-installing executable using WinRAR?

Tags: installation, winrar, self-extracting

I've seen executables that extract themselves and run a compressed `setup.exe` afterwards: a double click on the file uncompresses it and then runs the formerly compressed `setup.exe`.

How can I accomplish this? I would like to use WinRAR, how can I make a self-extracting executable that runs the compressed `setup.exe` after unpacking it to a temporary folder?

Comment: I think this question may be more appropriate on superuser.com.

Answer (score 17):

New Archive, set to SFX mode. Go to Advanced tab, SFX Options button.

General tab, "Run after extraction" textbox. Enter your setup.exe, with relative path if any.

[image: screenshot]

Then go to Modes tab and set it to Temporary mode:

[image: screenshot 2]

It will not prompt the user if you leave the question fields blank, and you can make it silent with the radio buttons at the bottom.

Comment: What about if I want to extract to `C:\Program Files\e-Sword`? - Where `Program Files` can be `Archivos de Programa` in spanish version of Windows XP.