# 7-zip self-extracting archive destination folder

Tags: c#, sfx

I am writing a C# program that call a self-extracting archive made using 7-zip. When the sfx file is called in

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sfx_exe);

The prompt for the directory to extract it appears. I would like to feed the directory right into the command so that the file will not require user input to extract.

I've read about using other installers but would ideally like to just pass a command into the execution of the sfx file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I silently install a 7-zip self-extracting archive to a specific directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687390/how-do-i-silently-install-a-7-zip-self-extracting-archive-to-a-specific-director)

Answer (score 0):

This is MOST likely a result of how the sfx file was made. I would recommend re-creating the self extracting SFX so that it doesn't prompt. Try using winrar, the user interface for creating self extracting files is comprehensive and and SFX can be created w/o a prompt http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm

Here is a guide on how to use the self extracting .exe feature:

[How do I make a self-installing executable using WinRAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265639/how-do-i-make-a-self-installing-executable-using-winrar)